# Help Identifying 5K* Potentiometer

Tags: identification, potentiometer

I am currently trying to replace a broken potentiometer in a therapy device ("KMI Hand mentor"). It is a 5k* potentiometer in plastic case/knob and comes in a through-hole version. The length of the shaft is 10mm and the actual package is approximately 90mm x 10mm x 5mm. Any equivalent form factor will work even if the resistance is different. The markings on the PCB just identify KMI and not the potentiometer. The white piece on the top (Figure 1) off the potentiometer can be pulled off (Figure 2).

So far the closest thing I've found is this: 
http://www.alps.com/WebObjects/catalog.woa/E/HTML/Potentiometer/RotaryPotentiometers/RK09Y11/RK09Y11_list.html

Any help identifying the manufacturer of this component would be appreciated.

Note: This work is being performed in an academic context, and the device (if fixed) will only be used for prototyping (not re-deployed).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sure it is 50k? I'd expect it to be 5k.

Comment: Since this is a "therapy device", don't touch it.  Get the manufacturer or authorized repair center to take care of it.  Even if something unrelated goes wrong and someone gets hurt and the other guy's lawyer finds out you made your own modifications, you're in big trouble.  The jury will hear how you mucked around with something without knowing what you were doing, and it will sound plenty incriminating.  Your insurance will refuse to pay, and you won't be able to participate here anymore unless they have internet service at the homeless shelter.

Comment: @jippie you are correct it is 5K
@ CamilStaps suggestions has been incorporated
@ Olin Lathrop: thanks for the information. I have added a clarification to show that this is only being used as a prototyping device.

Answer (score 3):

It seems this potentiometer belongs to the F10KV6 series by Favor (or Polyshine). It falls under the category of "rotary joystick potentiometers". The form factor seems to be the same as the original (even though the resistance could be different). The ultimate confirmation would be to obtain one, but since the minimum order quantity from the suppliers found is 1000 units this is unlikely.

SE Note:
Since this is along the lines of the information I was hoping to obtain I am posting this as an answer rather than a comment. [If it is inappropriate for me to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions), feel free to take whatever corrective action is necessary.

http://www.switches.co.kr/f10kv6.htm

http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/717840000/10mm_Joystick_Rotary_Potentiometer_F10KV6.html

[image: F10KV6 Joystick Potentiometer]

Comment: Answering your wn question is fine, specifically described in th FAQ